# Differentiating Integrals

Tags: statistics, derivatives

This problem appears as example 2d of Chapter 5 in "A First Course in Probability - Ross, 8th ed."

Suppose that if you are s minutes early for an appointment, then you incur the cost cs, and if you are s minutes late, then you incur the cost ks. Suppose also that the travel time from where you presently are to the location of your appointment is a continuous random variable having probability density function f . Determine the time at which you should depart if you want to minimize your expected cost.

If we let X denote travel time, and you leave t minutes before your appointment, then your cost, $C_t(x)$ is given by:

$C_t(x)$ = c(t - X) if X $\le$ t

$C_t(x)$ = k(X - t) if X $\ge$ t

Therefore,

E[$C_t(x)$] = $\int_0^tC_t(x)f(x)dx$

= $\int_0^tc(t - x)f(x)dx$ + $\int_t^{\infty}k(x - t)f(x)dx$

= ct$\int_0^tf(x)dx$ - c$\int_0^txf(x)dx$ + k$\int_t^{\infty}xf(x)dx$ - kt$\int_t^{\infty}f(x)dx$

The value of t that minimizes E[$C_t(x)$] can be obtained by:

$\frac{d}{dt}$E[$C_t(x)$] =  ct*f(t) + c*F(t) - ct*f(t) - kt*f(t) + kt*f(t) - k[1 - F(t)]

= (k + c)F(t) - k

Could someone please explain the steps involved in this differentiation?

Comment: Assuming $f(0)=0$, you can integrate $E(C_t(x))$ (by parts where necessary) and then differentiate. Edit: actually you don't need to assume $f(0)=0$, it's constant so it drops out when you differentiate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) the derivative with respect to $t$ of $\int_a^t g(x)\,dx$ is $g(t)$.

Let us look at the first term $ct\int_0^t f(x)\,dx$.  This is a product, we use the Product Rule. The derivative is $ct$ times the derivative of $\int_0^t f(x)\,dx$, plus $\int_0^t f(x)\,dx$ times the derivative of $ct$.

The next two terms are easier. For example, by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, the derivative with respect to $t$ of $c\int_0^t xf(x)\,dx$ is $ctf(t)$.  The fourth term is handled much like the first term..

Note that $\int_0^t f(x)\,dx$ can also be written as $F(t)$.